# C++ doesnt print a string defined as "string s(n,k);" and then resized

Tags: c++, io

I was trying out this code but it doesnt print anything :| , what's the problem?

```
    string bitmask(3, 1); 
    bitmask.resize(5, 0); 
    cout << bitmask;
```

P.S: I'm new to c++ (I come from python)

Btw the code print other strings defined as `string s="string";`

Comment: `1` and `'1`' are two different things.  The first is an integer the second is a character.  You want to use the character when doing things with strings.

Comment: Did you mean `std::string bitmask(3, '1'); bitmask.resize(5, '0');` instead? 1 and 0 are unprintable characters, but `'1'` and `'0'` are printable.

Comment: @RetiredNinja -- I suspect the questioner meant exactly what the code says. Corrections should address the code, not the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

If I use '1' or '0' instead of 1 or 0 the string is printed. But the code doesnt work well anymore :(.

```
void comb(int N, int K)
{
    std::string bitmask(K, 1); // if I write bitmask(K,'1') it doesnt work
    bitmask.resize(N, 0); // if I write bitmask.resize(N,'0') it doesnt work
    std::cout << bitmask // this doesnt print anything

    // print integers and permute bitmask
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // [0..N-1] integers
        {
            if (bitmask[i]) std::cout << " " << i;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(),bitmask.end()));
}
```

This code must print all combinations of a list of n number [0,1,2,...,n-1]. If I write '0' instead of 0 it doesnt work well anymore

Comment: That should be `if (bitmask[i] == '1')` or `if (bitmask[i] != '0')`

Comment: This isn't an answer. You should edit your question to include this code.

Comment: Characters, booleans and integers, don't know about Python but in C++ they are all different things.

Comment: @RetiredNinja sorry that my first thread opened on StOv.

Comment: @john yeah I've understood. But why the code works anyway if I write 0 and 1 (instead of '0' and '1'), but simply it doesnt print the string?

Comment: @RadiateSenga Because 1 and 0 will automatically convert to a boolean, 1 is true and 0 is false. But 1 and 0 do not convert to the characters '1' and '0', instead they convert to the characters with ASCII values of 1 and 0, and those characters are unprintable.

Comment: Pretty sure it does, but a string that starts with the 0 character ends immediately.

Comment: @Moige That's not true of a C++ string, only a C string.

Comment: Is that so? The more you know. Anyways, analyzing this new code I understand the issue. You can't both have printable characters in bitmask (that would get printed with a cout and readable as a row of 0s and 1s) AND have the bitmask[i] of these characters be a valable test (because '0' is like 48 iirc, so `if ('0')` passes). If you use printable characters you'll have to check `bitmap[i] == '1'`, if not, you can't print bitmask as is (and you might as well just use an array of bool).

Comment: *this doesnt print anything*  That is not true (although because it has no end-of-statement `;` it doesn't even compile).  Fixing the typo, `./a.out | xxd -g 1 -` shows that it does print something.  It is printing `'\x01'` (soh) and `'\x00'` (nul) characters.